# Using third-party jar files for execution in my maven plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

I am developing a maven plugin, which uses a third party jar file , in the sense that it execs this jar.

So what all this plugin does it , uses this specific third part jar, executes using some parameters , and thats the end of it.

I know there is a java exec plugin for maven, but for reasons of my own , I do not want to use that and rather go for this approach.

The issue is, I am not able to embed the jar file , unless it exists in the same directory as the pom.xml , for the project I would be using this plugin for.

Can someone suggest a robust and elegant way to do this?

### Thanks

Neeraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this JAR a dependency for the plugin you are developing.

Comment: That would only help me have a jar in my project folder right?

Comment: You will have the JAR (in the plugin's classpath) and therefore you can invoke it -- which is your primary goal.